# Finding the integer sequences

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I found a [kata](https://www.codewars.com/kata/582aad136755daf91a000021) on Codewars called 'Find the integer sequences'.

A function accepts a positive integer `n` and we have to find all the integer sequences between 1 and `n` for which the sum is equal to `n`. Then we have to return an array of those sequences sorted by ascending order of the length of sequences.

Below is my solution which did not pass tests because it is not efficient enough. How can I improve my code to make it more performant?

I don't ask you to resolve the problem for me, but rather to give me some hints to help me solve this a more efficient way. Thanks.

```
function findSequences(n){
  const result = []
  let acc

  for (let i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    acc = []
    for (let j = i; j < n; j++) {
      acc.push(j)
      if (acc.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr) == n) {
        result.push(acc)
        break
      }
    }
  }  

  return result.sort((a,b) => a.length > b.length ? 1 : -1)
  
}
```

Comment: Do you need the reduce?

Comment: How about `Math.ceil(n/2)` instead of `i < n` and `j < n`? For example, if `n = 20`, `9+10 < 20`, but `10+11 > 20`. If `n = 19`, `9+10 = 19`, but `10+11 > 19`. A max number is `n/2` (round up).

Comment: You should look at the standard [gaussian sum formula](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gau%C3%9Fsche_Summenformel) (don't have any english page for it, probably mostly known as such in germany), and then notice, that any integer sequence's sum is `gaussSum(end) - gaussSum(start - 1)`. You said don't solve the problem, so i currently won't get more specific. If you want full solutions, codewars always allows giving up, and checking other people's solutions.

Comment: don't sort: your insertion order should already be fine. If it's not, either run `i`, or `j`, or both, in the opposite direction. Also, no need for `reduce`: you can track the running tally per `i` in another array (e.g. `values`) in addition to working with `acc`,

Comment: Also note that if you don't want solutions, and your code _works_, but it's just not efficient enoiugh, this is probably the wrong place to ask and https://codereview.stackexchange.com might be a better place for this question. You're not just posting for yourself, you're also posting for everyone else with the same problem, so posts to SO should conclude with a real answer; people don't come here for hints, they come here for solutions =)

Comment: Thank you for those answers. Will consider [stackexchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for those kind of questions in a near future.

Comment: You may want to have a look at the concept of a partition in number theory. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory) I think you're computing the partition function. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(number_theory)

Answer (score 3):

I think I went kinda overkill on that problem.
In this problem, we are looking for Arithmetic progressions with a difference of one between the values.
We know that the sum is an integer, all the elements are integers and the number of elements is in integer.

This is one representation for the Arithmetic progression formula.
[image]

we can subsitute **d = 1** and solve for n to get that
[image]

If n is in an integer we know that such sequence exists, which is `a,a+1,...,a+n`
If n is not in integer, then no such sequence exists.

Secondly, we dont need to check all the sequences starts for the sum, because one the start is better then the half of the sum, we cannot create such sequence.

following this logic we can use the following code:

```js
function findSequences(n){
    sequences = [];
    for(var i = 1; i < Math.ceil(n/2) ; i++){
        var m = (-2 * i + 1 + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(2*i-1,2)+8 * n))/2;
        if(Number.isInteger(m)){
            sequences.push(Array.from({length:m},(_,index)=>index+i))
        }
    }
    return sequences.reverse();
}
```

I only added the reverse function cause the site demended the sequences in reverse from what I got.

Comment: Thank you for this mathematical way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

### Issue

The reasons why your code failed the test due to a timeout are as follows:

1. `i < n` and `j < n`: A maximum number that composes `n` is `n/2`(round up). -> Use `Math.ceil(n/2)` because if `n = 20`, `9+10 < 20`, but `10+11 > 20`. If `n = 19`, `9+10 = 19`, but `10+11 > 19`. A max number is `n/2` (round up)
2. `acc.push(j)` in the `for` loop makes arrays again and again including unnecessary results.

### Solution

Here is my solution that is similar to your approach. I think Daniel Botnik's answer is better and more mathematical though.

```
function findSequences(n){
  let result = [];
  if (n <= 1) return result;

  // Create an array of sequence
  // For example, if n=7 -> [1,2,3,4]
  let sequence = Array.from({length: Math.ceil(n / 2)}, (_, i) => i+1);
  
  for (let i = 0; i < sequence.length; i++) {
    let sum = 0;
    
    for (let j = i; j < sequence.length; j++) {
      sum += sequence[j];
      if (sum === n) {
        // If sum === n, add the sequence to the array.
        result.push(sequence.slice(i, j+1));
        break;
      }
      if (sum > n) {
        break;
      }
    }
    
  }
  
  return result.reverse();
}
```

Comment: This is smart. Thanks.

Comment: I find it slightly amazing, that the `if (sum > n) { break; }` appears to turn this something similar to O(n) (at least judging from a few tests), contrary to what it looks like, with the two loops. Loooots of skipped iterations :)